# fatloat address restrictions in u-boot

Tags: linux, u-boot, freertos, bare-metal

Can someone explain the restrictions around the address to load the binary in u-boot using fatload? Can I load the application into any address?

Also, if this address is dependent on the binary file, how can I extract it from my application binary file?

The context is, I have an application binary and the following executes the application.

```
fatload mmc 0 0x1C000000 application.bin
go 0x1C000000
```

However, I have changed the version of u-boot and when I call `go 0x1C000000`, it hangs.

Comment: AFAIK the address for fatload cannot be any address. It depends on your board because usually it should be address from SRAM or DRAM.

Comment: So, you mean independent of what binary I am loading, the address should always be fixed for a given board?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe it precisely enough. I meant that you need to know where are the SRAM or DRAM memories mapped into your board. You need to know range of the addresses of those memory, and there you could try to place the binary. It doesn't mean that the begin address must be always the same. It may vary but it must be in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

When you're talking about using the **go** command, which transfers execution to the address that you specify, you must load your application into memory at the address that you linked it to run at when building your application.

Comment: Oh I see! Is there anyway to find out what that address is from the binary file? like using objdumb or something similar?

Comment: For a binary it can be a lot more tricky.  But if you have the source, it will show where it's linked at while building.

Comment: I have the source, I will look into it. In the meanwhile, these two commands still work with the old version of u-boot. it is only problematic when I use the new u-boot. so I doubt it is due the address. do you have experience?